# Why is httpd throwing permissions denied for error_log?

Tags: linux, apache, centos, centos7, selinux

I created a new directory:

```
mkdir -p /webapps/logs
```

Then I set the context and permissions so apache could write to it:

```
chcon -Rv --type=httpd_sys_content_t /webapps/logs
chmod 2770 -Rv /webapps
chgrp -Rv webadmins /webapps
```

Apache is a member of that group:

```
grep webadmins /etc/group
#Prints out: webadmins:x:1002:apache
```

And webadmins is the owning group of the directory:

```
stat -c "%U %G" /webapps/logs
#Prints out: root webadmins
```

So why do I get a permission denied when starting httpd on /webapps/logs/error_log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this](https://blog.lysender.com/2015/07/centos-7-selinux-php-apache-cannot-writeaccess-file-no-matter-what/), I need to change the SELinux context to be "rw":

```
chcon -Rv --type=httpd_sys_rw_content_t /webapps/logs
```

This fixes the issue.